# Combine two html files in October CMS

Tags: octobercms

[image]

I have two files filename_in_content & filename_in_contentaotherdemo.
I want to clear filename_in_content data and replace with the contents of filename_in_contentanotherdemo file.I want to do with backend.These two are content types.

Comment: i guess when you click on them right side you are able to edit its content, so just click `filename_in_contentanotherdemo ` file from right side select its content `copy` it then, open `filename_in_content` and paste content to that file and save it. not sure i guessed it correct - it is what you want correct ?

Comment: nop actually filename_in_content is the real file.And the demo one is the preview file.When I click confirm button the original file data will be replace with the demo file's data.That is what I want. Thanks!

Comment: means where is confirm button, you want implementation like that am i correct

Comment: yes @HardikSatasiya

Comment: hmm then first naming should be consistent 'originalfile' for this file demo file can be named like `originalfile_demo` then we can add some sort of button on `demo file` when we `press confirm` if will remove `_demo` from its name and search that file and replace `originalfile` content with its content.